# Wrong stroke width when scaling a group in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

My document contains two rectangles. It works as expected to scale the width for instance, i.e. all stroke widths are equal. Even if I have selected both objects.

But if these objects are grouped together and I scale the width of that group, things go crazy and the width of the strokes are **not** equal anymore:
[image: unequal stroke widths after scaling]

Any ideas? Is that intended behaviour?
I am using Inkscape v1.0.2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15)

I looked into the XML code, but that looks sane at a first glance, but I am inexperienced with that kind of stuff.

Btw, the behaviour is unrelated to the `Transforms | Scale stroke width` preference. Furthermore it also happens if the preference `Transforms | Store transformation` is set to `Optimized`.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/72048/inkscape-problem-rectangle-with-unequal-stroke-width seems to be **unrelated**.

Comment: Is there any preferred way to attach a minimal example document?

Comment: You can share the SVG at SVGshare.com - no need to sign up for an account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Inkscape changes the actual parameters (like the `width` and `height` attributes of a rectangle) of objects directly when changed separately, but simply just adds a `transform` attribute to groups. Changing the scale with `transform` stretches/distorts the objects visually, including the stroke.

When the option 'Store transformation' in the preferences under 'Behaviour → Transforms' is set to 'Optimized', simply ungrouping then regrouping should, in most cases, apply the transform to each object and fix the stroke. Alternatively try [this extension](https://github.com/Klowner/inkscape-applytransforms) to recursively apply `transform` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what user @Xrott has already said (which is the correct answer BTW) . . .

In terms of the SVG, you can see what's going on here, and how a transform is applied to a group, but not when the objects are ungrouped. All I did to achieve this here was simply to ungroup to apply the transform.

```
  <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,4.93,0,-130)" stroke-width=".689">
   <rect x="17.5" y="42.7" width="24.3" height="11.5" ry=".17" opacity=".55"/>
   <rect x="48.5" y="33.2" width="30.7" height="14.6" ry=".17" opacity=".55" stroke-width="1.49"/>
   <rect x="58.2" y="53.7" width="26.4" height="12.5" ry=".17" opacity=".55" stroke-width="2.99"/>
  </g>
  <rect x="115" y="81.8" width="24.3" height="56.7" ry=".838" opacity=".55" stroke-width="1.53"/>
  <rect x="146" y="35" width="30.7" height="72" ry=".838" opacity=".55" stroke-width="3.31"/>
  <rect x="156" y="136" width="26.4" height="61.6" ry=".838" opacity=".55" stroke-width="6.64"/>
```

Note also that in my example above the stroke widths are scaled when the stretch is applied to the ungrouped objects. If you don't want that to happen, you can change that option in the preferences. Uncheck "Scale stroke width"

[image]